# How to change dll into release mode in VS2012?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a windows 8 application. Inorder to load pdf in my application I am using MuPDF library which is downloaded from github. I have added MuPDFWinRT.vcxproj in my solution and this project reference is added in my aaplication. My application renders pdf successfully. As part of uploading application to windows store, tested with Windows App Certification Kit .

The test failed and i got the following error "**The binary MuPDFWinRT.dll is built in debug mode**." I have given Release mode in configuarationmanager but still getting the error. I have also tried to update Windows App Certification Kit but that also failed.

Can we install  Windows App Certification Kit 3.1 on Windows 8?
Please help..

Comment: The DLL you downloaded was created in debug mode. Sounds like you will need to find and download this MuPDF library again, this time making sure it's compiled in release mode.

Comment: I am new to this third party project integration. How can I make sure that it is in release mode?

Answer (score 1):

The DLL you downloaded was created in debug mode.

Sounds like you will need to find and download this MuPDF library again, this time making sure it's compiled in release mode.
only the author of the DLL can make sure that...

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded it from GitHub, i am sure you get `two set of binaries`, one for `debug mode` and other for `release mode`. You have used Debug mode binaries, refer Release mode binaries instead.

Relative path is like this: `~\MuPDF.WinRT-master\MuPDF.WinRT-master\Binaries\v0.5\Win8_v0.5\Win8\Win32\Release`.

---

In case you have added **.vcxproj** directly to your solution, you need to build that project with Configuration set to `Release` mode.

Open Configuration Manager from Build Menu *(Build -> Configuration Manager)* and change Configuration for your project to `Release` mode.

But i would suggest to change Configuration for your solution from `Debug` to `Release` mode and build solution in release mode so that release mode binaries emit for all your projects.